# Teradata Fast export connection in Informatica misbehaving

Tags: teradata, informatica, fastexport

We are using Teradata Fastexport connection in Informatica to export data from few tables by joining them in Source Qualifier query and write to a CSV file. We have around 180 columns to pull, recently we added 2 new columns to this flow and we found that data for few of the records looks junk. We figured out those records and tried to run the SQ query only for those records, to our surprise the columns which were junk earlier now throwing us expected data.

Is there any fast export limitation to export the columns ? or any properties should be increased at Informatica level.

We are clueless on this issue, please help.

Comment: There's no limitation of the FastExport protocol. Does Informatica create the CSV? Then it's probably better to switch a TPT Export (Informatica should support that, too) which supports writing CSV directly.

Comment: CSV file is getting generated but for few columns data is scrambled. We are not sure why this is happening. If we filter for particular error record and run our job then everything looks good in the output file.